# Import stock index components from Yahoo!Finance into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I'm Trying to get a list of FTSE100 components from Yahoo Finance as an XML file to further import it into MySQL database.

The best link to an XML file that I managed to get is [this](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%2Fcp%3Fs%3D%255EFTSE%2BComponents%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys), which doesn't look like an XML to me at all..

Does anybody know how to get a proper XML file for index components from Yahoo or maybe a way to work with this one?

Comment: Did you see this? https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit, but consider adding a bit more details to clarify what you're asking.